# How to fix com.mysql.jdbc.DocsConnectionPropsHelper

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to connect a Swing app with DB and every time this issue appears

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Connn { private static Connection connexion ;      

static {
try {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");  
connexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ds2","root", "");
System.out.println("Connexion établie");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("connexion impossible");
     e.printStackTrace();
}}
public static Connection getConnexion() 
{return connexion;}
}
```

Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale com.mysql.jdbc.DocsConnectionPropsHelper

Comment: Does the oracle jdbc driver even use a class from `com.mysql`? This is weird

Comment: So what should i do 
i am new here !!!!

Comment: is com.mysql.jdbc.DocsConnectionPropsHelper in your classpath?